# Postgresql - Error in function that returns table

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I just defined this function to return all column names from a given table:

```
create or replace function GET_COLUMNS(in tbl_name character varying(30))
returns table(colunas character varying) as $$
begin
    SELECT column_name
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_schema = 'Main'
    AND table_name   = tbl_name;
end;
$$ language 'plpgsql'
```

But When I call it using `select * from get_columns('tabfuncionarios');` I just got the following error:

> ```
> ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
> HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function get_columns(character varying) line 3 at SQL statement
> ```

I'm using `postgresql 9.4.5` version

Comment: One more thing: It hardly makes sense to define the input parameter as `character varying(30)`. Just use `varchar` (without maximum length) or `text`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add `RETURN QUERY` to the start of your query:

```
create or replace function GET_COLUMNS(in tbl_name character varying(30))
returns table(colunas character varying) as $$
begin
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT column_name
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_schema = 'Main'
    AND table_name   = tbl_name;
end;
$$ language plpgsql
```

Answer (score 6):

You don't need `plpgsql` for this. A plain `sql` function will do:

```
create or replace function GET_COLUMNS(in tbl_name character varying(30))
   returns table(colunas character varying) 
as 
$$
    SELECT column_name
    FROM information_schema.columns
    WHERE table_schema = 'Main'
    AND table_name   = tbl_name;
$$ 
language sql;
```

Additionally: the language name is an *identifier*. Don't put it in single quotes.